# Bluetooth RSSI measurement during discovery

Tags: android, bluetooth

Can the RSSI of a BT device be measured during discovery, i.e. before pairing? If so, how to do it in Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get the RSSI for the device discovered , 
See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#EXTRA_RSSI)

Comment: Thanks. But do you agree with Femi that a program can't even iterate through all discovered devices?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible for a standard Android program: you have no visibility into non-paired devices from a non-system APK.

If you are on a rooted device and have the appropriate permission you can access the dbus socket used by the bluetooth subsystem and that information is available through the bluez api.

Comment: Can an Android program not see all of the discovered (unpaired) devices? Doesn't the snippet at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices allow the program to iterate through all discovered devices?

Comment: Not before pairing: after pairing, sure. Not before.

Comment: But doesn't the example snippet allow the iteration through all discovered devices? If so can't a program simply read the extra RSSI attribute as Dennis has suggested?

Comment: Well, you are certainly wecome to try, but no: you currently (as of 2.3 on a standard device) can not iterate through unpaired devices.